# CS50 PSET 9 finance

Tags: python, cs50

I have written code in python such that when a user can purchase stock as seen below.

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")

    if request.method == "POST":

        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")

        stock = lookup(symbol)
        cash_db = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"] )
        cash = cash_db[0]["cash"]
        share = request.form.get("share")

        if not share:
            return apology("must provide share")

        if int(share) < 0:
            return apology("must provide greater than 0 share")

        if not symbol:
            return apology("must provide symbol")

        if stock == None:
            return apology("Stock does not exist")

        cost = int(share) * stock["price"]

        if cost > cash:
            return apology("Insuffcient balance")

        balance = cash - cost

        db.execute("UPDATE users set cash = ? WHERE id = ?", balance ,session["user_id"])

        now = datetime.datetime.now()

        buy = "buy"

        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol ,shares ,price ,date, type) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) ",session["user_id"], stock["symbol"], share, stock["price"], now, buy)

        return redirect("/")
```

However I am getting this runtime error every time I create a new account and immediately try to buy the stock.
[image]
[image]

But when I logout the user and then relogin with the account and purchase the stock everything works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "But when I logout the user and then relogin with the account and purchase the stock everything works"—you haven't shown us how accounts get created, or how logging out and logging in work. It looks like you might not be setting `session["user_id"]` correctly.

Comment: It looks like `session["user_id"]` is the entire user object, not just the user id.  How is that being saved to the session?

Comment: The comment from @JohnGordon looks spot on. When that is fixed,  you will have trouble with `now` because that is a python datetime object. Better to use sqlite `datetime('now')` in the INSERT into transactions sql.